# Lyrics contain the idiom "for one thing"

Tags: lyrics

I am looking for lyrics which contain the idiom "for one thing".
What I want is that the idiom must be explained as "for example" or "for instance".
I have found three songs which seem to satisfy the condition.
But I am not sure the connotation of the idiom in the lyrics.
Could anyone help me check it? Thanks.

If the following three songs don't contain the idiom,
could you please provide songs which have the idiom.

1. I Threw It All Away
   Bob Dylan

I once held her in my arms
She said she would always stay
But I was cruel
I treated her like a fool
I threw it all away

Once I had mountains in the palm of my hand
And rivers that ran through every day
I must have been mad
I never knew what I had
Until I threw it all away

Love is all there is, it makes the world go 'round
Love and only love, it can't be denied
No matter what you think about it
You just won't be able to do without it
Take a tip from one who's tried

So if you find someone that gives you all of her love
Take it to your heart, don't let it stray
`For one thing` that's certain
You will surely be a-hurtin'
If you throw it all away
If you throw it all away

2. Perfect Proposal
   Wayne Wonder

This is for my baby..

will you marry me
by your side ill be (pretty lady)
Will you marry me (will you)
by your side i'll be.

[refrain]
I think it's time to be a host to my baby,
i think it's time make a toast to my baby,
i think it's time to just propose to my lady,
will you marry me? [2x]

Your truly the best, a bless, the greatest girl i know,
you made my life worth living, baby and it shows.
I want to have you see
loser to me,
to feel happy home.
i want to promise that i'll never leave you alone.

`For one thing` i'm really sure for you my love has no way?
And nothing in this world can separate us,
So until then

[refrain]

Not a day go by that I don't think of you.
Sitting here contemplating will my dreams come true.
No one is perfect in life, but you're so perfect for me.
I can't describe how your love sets me free.
My life won't be okay until you're by my side.
Without you i'd be empty, so be my bride!

[refrain]

Will you marry me?
By your side i'll be.
Will you marry me?
By your side i'll be!

`For one thing` i'm really sure for you my love has no way?
And nothing in this world can separate us,
So until then

[refrain]

3. One of the Fortunate Few
   Delbert McClinton

Well, `for one thing`, there was a whole lot of guys
Who would've liked to have been in my shoes
But the upkeep on a woman like that
Will give an old poor boy the blues

Still the pleasure was worth the pain
Of everything she put me through
And I consider myself one of the fortunate few

Yeah and another thing she wasn't just good looking
Her imagination just wouldn't quit
She'd make you do things you never thought about
And things you wouldn't want to admit

There must be somebody else out there
That feels about her like I do
And I consider myself one of the fortunate few

It felt so good to hurt so bad
The best and the worst that I ever had
I know I bit off a little more than I could chew
Still, I consider myself, one of the fortunate few

Well, the last thing I'm gonna tell you
Some things are better left unsaid
A gentleman don't go talkin' about
What happens in a woman's bed

That's all I've got to say
I'll leave the rest up to you
But I consider myself one of the fortunate few

Comment: The Delbert McCliton song is definitely idiomatic. However, the Dylan is not: he means "there is one thing" rather than "for example." I interpret the Wayne Wonder song the same way, though it's somewhat ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [search for 'for one reason'](http://www.mldb.org/search?mq=for%20one%20thing&si=3&mm=2&ob=1) of [The Music Lyrics Database](https://www.mldb.org/) gives 40 results, of which only 1 is idiomatic in the manner of "for example".

- Tiny Sick Tears, by Frank Zappa

> I know that its so hard stop playing this soul music, you know, cause it really . . . For one thing its really easy . . . And for another thing: It wastes a lot of time while were on stage.

And even this one is dialogue at the end of the song, not necessarily part of the main lyrics.

Comment: Got it! Thanks. The website you recommended is faster than the one (lyrics.com) I used. I often use the syntax "bla bla" site:lyrics.com in google search. The advantage is that I can preview the lyrics. Would you like to add the comment above to your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a site I've been a big fan of, with a lyric search function, if it helps.
[Here](https://songmeanings.com/query/?query=for%20one%20thing&type=lyrics)

Comment: Hi @JacobZeller. Glad to welcome you to SE Music Fans. As a new participant, please have a look at this page on [writing a good answer](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), particularly the section called "Provide context for links". It will help bring your answer in line with others on the site. Cheers -Aaron

Answer (score 0):

Out of your original examples, only the third song, the Delbert McClinton, is using "for one thing" to mean "for example." In the other songs, the words "for one thing" are just a part of a larger phrase, that is not idiomatic. The key giveaway is the comma (or lack thereof). When it's there, it sets off those three words, and makes it likely that they are being used with the idiomatic sense you're looking for.

But now I'm very curious as to why you need this :D